# at the lowest possible price?

Tags: meaning

> However, in reality, large-scale farming frequently fails to guarantee
> animal welfare. In some countries so-called ‘factory farming’ is
> tolerated, when animals such as pigs, calves, hens, cattle – all
> clearly capable of suffering – are kept in very confined and crowded
> conditions, and treated as simply the means to produce meat, eggs, or
> dairy produce **at the lowest possible price**, with negligible concern
> for the pain endured by the animals. It is unlikely that any
> utilitarian calculation could justify such practices.

Philosohphy : the basics

Does "at the lowest possible price" have the same meaning as "at the price as low as posible"?

Comment: the highest, the lowest, the most beautiful. versus: as high as, as low as, as beautiful as. "at the price as low as possible" is not grammatical.

Comment: What part of this confuses you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the right idea, though your rewording needs perhaps a couple more words, "at the price [that is] as low as possible." It means the lowest price that is possible.